# Efficient way to concatenate multi-lines of SQL statements in Java?

Tags: java, sql

Is there a way to efficiently concatenate multiple lines of strings in SQL statements in Java?
As a developer who works with long SQL statements, I'm searching for a way to do this.

Comment: Are there any dynamic parts in that (that cannot be avoided with bind variables) or are you just asking for multi-line String literals ?

Comment: As a .net developer, I often use the StringBuilder - also available in java - class to concatenate long sql queries in strings.

Comment: Or use a dedicated lib with interpolation and multilinear string, simply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can allocate a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) with enough room for the whole result, and then use its `append` to append the pieces, converting to string when you're done with `toString`:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(/*...number big enough for the whole thing...*/);
sb.append("SELECT [Foo], [Bar] FROM ");
sb.append(tableName); // **NOT** from a user, from internal logic
sb.append(" WHERE [X] = ?");
try (PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sb.toString())) {
    ps.setString(1, /*...*/); // This can be user-derived
    // ...
}
```

Be sure you **don't** put any user-derived information in the SQL via `StringBuilder` or other string-combining methods. That way lies SQL injection attacks... Let me introduce you to [my friend Bobby](https://bobby-tables.com/):

[image]

Instead, for that part, use prepared statements and parameters as shown with `[X] = ?` and `ps.setString` (and comments) in the example above.

Answer (score 1):

Nicer to look at may be that, though.

```
String pattern = 
        "INSERT INTO %s (%s,%s,%s) " +
        "VALUES (?,?,?)";
String query = String.format(pattern, "T", "C1", "C2", "C3");
```

Where T, C1 etc must not be taken from user input directly.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the above answers, JDK 13 introduces [text blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/text_blocks/index.html) as a preview feature, which allows text blocks like that:

```
String message = """
    'The time has come,' the Walrus said,
    'To talk of many things:
    Of shoes -- and ships -- and sealing-wax --
    Of cabbages -- and kings --
    And why the sea is boiling hot --
    And whether pigs have wings.'
    """;
```

Note that this is a preview feature, which shall not be used in production yet. Has to be enabled with `--enable-preview` command line arg.

Comment: ah, cool. Btw Scala is a much nicer language giving you string interpolation.

Comment: Yes, Scala had it for ages.