# NativeQuery to DELETE duplicate Oracle SQL Db table entries does not work (see code)

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, junit

I'm trying to write code for checking a table for duplicate rows, and deleting all but one of the flagged rows(keep one, delete the duplicates). I'm using JPA NativeQuery as below with the following SQL command:

```
  @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

  public void findandDeleteDupDogs() {

    String deleteString =
        "DELETE FROM DOGS";
    String wherestring = "WHERE rowid not in";
    String selectminstring = "(SELECT MIN(rowid)";
    String fromstring = "FROM DOGS";
    String groupbystring = "GROUP BY NAME, SPECIES)";


    String sqlString =
        String.format(
            "%s %s %s %s %s ",
            deleteString,
                wherestring,
                selectminstring,
                fromstring,
                groupbystring);

    try {
      Query query = em.createNativeQuery(sqlString);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error(e.getMessage());
    }

  }
```

Function to `SELECT * FROM TABLE` to check if deletion has gone through:

```
  public List<Dog> selectAll(){
String selectString = "SELECT * FROM DOGS";

Query query = em.createNativeQuery(selectString);

try {
  List<Dog> results = query.getResultList();
  return results;
} catch (Exception e) {
  log.error(e.getMessage());
  return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

}

My Junit test is as below testing the code's workability:

```
@Before
  public void setUp() throws InterruptedException {

    batchRepo.save(batch);
    propertyRepo.save(property);

    dog1 = createSameDog();
    dog2 = createSameDog();
    dog3 = createSameDog();
    dog4 = createSameDog();
    dog5 = createDifferentDog();


    DogRepo.save(dog1);
    DogRepo.save(dog2);
    DogRepo.save(dog3);
    DogRepo.save(dog4);
    DogRepo.save(dog5);
  }
```

The first test which tested the SELECT statement worked fine:

```
  @Test
  public void testSelectStatement(){
    assertThat(DogRepository.selectAll().size()).isEqualTo(5);
  }
```

The Second test failed:

```
  @Test
  public void deletedupdogs() {
    DogRepository.findandDeleteDupDogs();
    assertThat(DogRepository.selectAll().size()).isEqualTo(2);
  }
```

This is the error:

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: 
Expecting:
 <5>
to be equal to:
 <2>
```

Which to my understanding, meant the query for function `findandDeleteDupDogs()` did nothing at all, and all five dogs(duplicates included) still exist.

I can't seem to understand what I did wrong, and would appreciate some fresh eyes looking at this, thanks!

Comment: can you try annotation `@Transcational` on `findandDeleteDupDogs`

Comment: Doesnt work. I placed that annotation at class level previously with no luck either

Comment: Did you check the result of the select clause in the delete statement? Does it return anything? Btw. there was a discussion today how to [create sql qeuries in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58362869/efficient-way-to-concatenate-multi-lines-of-sql-statements-in-java/58362914#58362914), may be of general interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `query.executeUpdate()`. Now you're only creating the queries without actually running them.

Comment: You, are a lifesaver. Thank you!